# Keycloak error type=LOGOUT_ERROR, error=invalid_token, client_auth_method=client-secret

Tags: keycloak

I am new to keycloak setup hence need your help. Please let me know if you need more information.
My web app returns invalid login when valid credentials are entered. Further look into my keycloak pod logs, i can the below error...

The keycloak version: 10.0.2

****[org.keycloak.events] (default task-211) type=LOGOUT_ERROR, realmId=qa-vanguard, clientId=qa-client, userId=null, ipAddress=x.x.x.x, error=invalid_token, client_auth_method=client-secret****

Any pointers on how to further debug the problem.
-Raman

Comment: The exception message says it's LOGOUT_ERROR, so looks like there is a logout operation happening, but for logout you should also pass the token which you previously acquired. It looks like either you are not passing the token or you token is invalid. Maybe you could debug with this hint

Comment: Thanks, Umakanth. Some more background on the problem. Our Login UI is hosted behind nginx ingress, when provided with login credentials hits keycloak for authtoken to access the backend services. Keycloak returns auth token, however, it gets expired in the backed API service. We would like to debug if indeed auth_token is returned properly to the UI application. Is there a way to enable logs in in ingress controller that can capture auth_token?

Comment: auth_token here I am assuming access_token ? If you are getting this access token in your backend API then you can log there as well. There are many reasons why access_token can be shown as expired even though it still has long lifespan. You would need to decode the token and understand it's contents(jwt.io). I believe you can also do a console.log in your front end application to check the api response. Sorry I have little experience in Ingress controller

Comment: @Umakanth, Mybad! it is access_token. Nonetheless, we are able to resolve the issue. The header big size  prevents the "access_token" from being send to backend API, which does token validation. This is resolved by nginx.org/server-snippets:
                           http2_max_field_size 64K;
                           http2_max_header_size 64K;
                           client_max_body_size 1024M;
                           client_header_buffer_size 1024M;
                           underscores_in_headers on;
                           large_client_header_buffers 12 256k;

Comment: We have set the below args in our portal ingress object -                                                                     nginx.org/server-snippets:
                           http2_max_field_size 64K;
                           http2_max_header_size 64K;
                           client_max_body_size 1024M;
                           client_header_buffer_size 1024M;
                           underscores_in_headers on;
                           large_client_header_buffers 12 256k;

Comment: Good to know that you resolved, I have faced similar issue in tomcat deployment model as well, I had to increase the header size.